# WP Session Manager - how to destroy session

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I've built a cart - using wp_session_manager https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-session-manager/

```
  $wp_session = WP_Session::get_instance();
 // Use it like an array - throw stuff on it
 unset($wp_session);
```

However, unsetting the session isn't working. I must be doing something wrong. I found this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/destroy-session/

```
unset($wp_session['sessionName']);
```

But I don't have a key of sessionName?

Comment: how about session_destroy();

Comment: thanks @BarclickFloresVelasquez - unfortunately, that doesn't work. 
`session_destroy(): Trying to destroy uninitialized session` - WP_session_manager seems to implement its own thing.

Comment: From the brief description of the plugin I see 'Every visitor, logged in or not, will be issued an instance of WP_Session. Their instance will be identified by an ID
stored in the _wp_session cookie' - so I guess I grab that ID and then unset... will give it a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The older version of WP Session Manager didn't use native sessions due to some limitations with hosting platforms like WP Engine. Since then, though, we've upgraded to use the database for storage (over options) and to use PHP's native session interface.

With a modern version (3.0 or above) you can leverage `session_destroy()` to clear the session data just fine.